# AD620 simulation Problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I am doing my FYP in which I am using AD620. I have problem in simulation. Attached is the circuit which i am implementing. Basically I need a gain of 5000. i.e My input should be amplified by 5000 times. I have calculated the value of the resistance as 0.0101194 ohms.When I place this resistance in my circuit and simulate it on proteus, it gives the error that the timestep too small.[image]

Comment: First of all, start working with physical values. 0.01\$\Omega\$ is not. It's less than some shorts...

Comment: You have two resistors in your circuit. Which one you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Ref ought to be tied to some voltage between the two power rails and you have an input open circuit, Example here: -

[image]

You will also find that the way you have pin 2 connected is illegal. Pin 2 fails to be a reliable input when it gets closer than 1.9 volts to the negative rail (pin 4) or ground in your circuit.

An input is amplified between pins 2 and pin 3 - I don't know where pin 3 is suppoed to be but pin 2 is at an illegal voltage (ground).

Also, using a pot to set a gain of 5000 is nonesence - the gain equation requires Rg to be about 10 ohms and a 20k pot will be as noisy as hell when trying to get the wiper ten ohms away from one end of the range - use a fixed resistor and take into account temperature drift (if necessary).

When you do get the inputs, Rg and pin 5 sorted out don't expect miracles from the output when powered on a 5V rail on ground. The DS specifies that the output can range from -Vs + 1.1V to +Vs - 1.2V and for a 5V supply that means you can rely ONLY on the output when it is between 1.1 volts and 3.8 volts.

> I have calculated the value of the resistance as 0.0101194 ohms

Gain = 1 + 49k/Rg so clearly Rg approximately equals 10 ohms.

Comment: my Friend according to the data sheet max gain is 1000